# “throw new HttpException” will not return anything error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code inside my action methods:-

```
public ActionResult ManageCustomerVLANs(string customerName)
        {
            if (!repository.IsCustomerExsists(customerName))
            {

               throw new HttpException(404, "Your error message");//RedirectTo NoFoundPage
            }
```

And I have defined the following inside my web.config, to handle any 404 http code:-

```
<caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>

          <add name="NoCache" noStore="true" duration="0" varyByParam="*"/>
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
    <!--<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>-->
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/" />
    </customErrors>
```

But currently if the action method return `“throw new HttpException”`, nothing is actually returned and the execution will continue after this `“throe new HttpException”`.
so can anyone advice, how I can return an http 404 ?

Comment: its better to return `HttpStatusCodeResult` instead as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148554/asp-net-mvc-4-throw-httpexception-vs-return-httpstatuscoderesult?rq=1

Comment: or you can try the way shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can return 404 like this.

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```